# Multiple Filters On Express-GraphQL

Tags: javascript, express, graphql

I'm using express-graphql and node-fetch in my application. I am trying to use graphql with my api call to grab data. Currently I am doing

```
const QueryType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "Query",
  fields: () => ({
    acctsFromRelation: {
      type: new GraphQLList(AcctType),
      args: {
       id: {type: GraphQLString},
       status: {type: GraphQLString}
      },
      resolve: (root, args) => getOpIds(args)
    }
  })
});
```

The AcctType is as follows

```
 const AcctType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "acct",
  fields: () => ({
    id: {type: GraphQLString},
    name: {type: GraphQLString},
    clientType: {type: GraphQLString},
    accountStatus: {type: GraphQLString,
    args: {
      status: {type: GraphQLString}
    }},
    primaryContact: {type: contactType},
    billingAddress: {type: billingType}
  })
});
```

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
{ acctsFromRelation (id: "2") {
  id
  name
  accountStatus (status: "active")
  primaryContact {
    firstName
    lastName
    phone
    email
  }
  billingAddress {
    address1
    address2
    city
    state
    postalCode
    country
  }
}
}
```

where i obtain all accounts with id of 2 and accountStatus of active.

GetOpIds is as follows:

```
function getOpIds (ids) {
  return fetch(API CALL THAT GIVES IDS)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => json.map((element) => getAccountByUrl(element.id)))
    .catch(err => err)
}
```

and getAccountByUrl looks like this

```
function getAccountByUrl (ids) {
  return fetch(URL THAT LOOKS UP 1 ID at a TIME)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => json)
    .catch(err => err)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this directly from the code

```
const query = `query AcctsFromRelation($id: ID, $status: String){acctsFromRelation(id: $id, status: $status)}`;
        const variables = { id: id, status: status };
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          request("/graphql", query, variables).then(data => {
            resolve(data.acctsFromRelation);
          });
        });
```